# Redirect to page produces "too many redirects" but target page is excluded in RewriteRule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Trying to redirect users to expired page after a set time but the browser gets stuck in a "too many redirects" loop.

The first line is the time condition and the second line excludes the redirect target page from RewriteRule.

Changing the RewriteRule matching regex to `^/$` or `^$` does nothing, the redirect gets ignored.

Here are the conds/rule:

```
    RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}%{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} >201904181540 [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !en-gb/expired$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en-gb/expired [L,R=301]
```

Target Url
https://mywebsite.com/en-gb/exipred

Example urls that get caught in loop:

`https://mywebsite.com/`

`https://mywebsite.com/en-gb`

`https://mywebsite.com/en-gb/home`

`https://mywebsite.com/en-gb/success`

Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: Rule should work fine. Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Networking tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.

Comment: The redirects may happen in another rule.